# run perlscript from emacs (cscript example //C:Perlscript)

Tags: perl, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

i would like to create a shortcut key for emacs to execute this command:

```
cscript example //C:Perlscript
```

with example.pl being the perl script that i want to execute

i already got a shortcut key for executing perl: (global-set-key (kbd "") 'perl-eval)
how do i make this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
(defun run-command () "Run hard coded shell command" (interactive)
   (shell-command (concat "cscript " buffer-file-name " //C:Perlscript")))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'run-command)
```

Comment: thats almost what i need, now the "example" should be replaced by the current active file, do you understand what i mean?